# Using RDLC subreport multiple times

Tags: c#, rdlc, subreport

I have a report that lists off taxes for a store given a storeID, a fromDate, and a toDate. I want to use this report as a subreport multiple times in the same parent report. For example, if you use storeID's 1,2,3,4,5 you would have this subreport show 5 times, with the first one having data for store 1, second one having data for store 2, etc.

Is this even possible? I've found some forums where people are asking how to use the same subreport twice in a report, but the threads always die out before they find something. I also saw you can use parameters but I'm not sure how those work (a bit new to sub-reporting in RDLC).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, probably you can use a single SubReport containing a Table displaying taxes grouped by store.

Comment: That's what I've tried but the thing is that since I'm using Local Reporting I can't use parameters, so if I have my single SupReportProcessingEventHandler, it will process the same individual store for every single SubReport in the table... and if I use a 'foreach store', then it will just use the last store selecteds datasource.

Comment: In .LocalReport.SubreportProcessing you have to pass the entire Dataset but you can filter it by setting Parameters in subreport properties.

Comment: Wouldn't that only work if I had a set number of SubReports though? I might have 1 store, or 8, or any number. If I use the parameter don't I have to specify which subreport uses which storeID? I can't just say the first SubReport uses the first StoreID, the second SubReport uses the second StoreID, etc?

Comment: You can set subreport parameters at runtime. I read your question again: maybe you can solve your problem simply using a Tablix grouped by store without using Subreport.

Comment: Yeah, that's starting to look like it may be my only option... It's not important on this particular report but would really help out for future reports if I could do it. Thanks for your help though, I'll update this if I ever figure out the other way.

Answer (score 0):

In the main report, use 5 instances of the subreport.
Change the (Name) property of each subreport, but keep the subreport path the same (as you already did).

When processing the main report, the method `LocalReport_SubReportProcessing` called many times according to instances count of the subreport found.

You'll make a global variable keeps the current store Id as in the code sampel below.

```
    public class TaxDetailsOfStore
    {
        public int StoreId { get; set; }

        // Your other details here...
    }

    // This global property be filled for all stores before displaying the main report.
    private List<TaxDetailsOfStore> TaxDetailsOfAllStores { get; set; }

    private int _storeId = 1; // To start with.
    private const int _maxStoreId = 5;

    private void LocalReport_SubReportProcessing(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {
        string reportDataSourceName = string.Empty;
        object reportDataSourceValue = null;

        switch (e.ReportPath)
        {
            case "SubRprtTaxDetailsOfStore":
                int storeId = Convert.ToInt32(e.Parameters["storeId"].Values[0]);
                var lstTaxDetailsOfStore = TaxDetailsOfAllStores.FindAll(x => x.StoreId == storeId);

                //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Increment the variable _storeId till reaches _maxStoreId and then back again from 1.
                _storeId = _storeId++ % _maxStoreId;
                //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                reportDataSourceName = "TaxDetailsOfStoreDataSet";
                reportDataSourceValue = lstTaxDetailsOfStore;
                break;

            // Handle other sub reports like this.
            //case "SubRprtAnother1":
            //    object dsSubRprtAnother1 = null;
            //    reportDataSourceName = "AnotherDataSetName1";
            //    reportDataSourceValue = dsSubRprtAnother1;
            //    break;

            //case "SubRprtSummary":
            //    object dsSubRprtSummary = null;
            //    reportDataSourceName = "SubRprtSummaryDataSet";
            //    reportDataSourceValue = dsSubRprtSummary;
            //    break;
        }

        ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource
        {
            Name = reportDataSourceName,
            Value = reportDataSourceValue
        };

        e.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
    }
```